# virt-manager: “Storage parameter error: directory is not managed on the remote host” when importing an existing image from a mounted drive

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

A server I manage remotely has a KVM/QEMU image stored on a non-os, mounted drive /mnt/drive.

When I use virt-manager to import the disk image, I get the following error:

```
Storage parameter error.
Cannot use storage '/mnt/drive/vms/vm1.img': '/mnt/drive/vms' is not managed on the remote host.
```